# Disabling/enabling elements of sizer in wxpython

Tags: wxpython

In wxpython you cannot disable/enable sizer and its items, so I decided to loop through sizer and disable them one by one.

My panel looks like this:

```
vertical_sizer
├── horizontal_sizer_1
│   └── dynamic_created_elements
└── horizontal_sizer_2
    └── dynamic_created_elements
```

Because my items are created dynamically, i don't know how many or what kind elements will be inside, so can't do it by their id.
So I have wrtitten this code:

```
for horizontal_sizer in self.my_sizer.GetChildren():
    for element in horizontal_sizer.GetChildren():
        element.Enable()
```

But i keep on getting error `AttributeError: 'SizerItem' object has no attribute 'GetChildren'` on my horizontal_sizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try calling `GetWindow()` on your `horizontal_sizer` item and print it out to determine if it is `None` or a widget you weren't expecting. My suspicion is that you have another widget inside of your vertical sizer that is not a sizer.

Alternatively you can use Python's `hasattr` to determine if the child item has `GetChildren()` as a method and if not, just skip it:

```
for horizontal_sizer in self.my_sizer.GetChildren():
    if hasattr(horizontal_sizer, 'GetChildren'):
        for element in horizontal_sizer.GetChildren():
            element.Enable()
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Rechecked few times, also tried `hasattr` as you sugested. Program is kinda complex so i could still be missing something. So because i couldn't make it work i created in my panel a list storing those elements needing a change. Not clean or pythonic solution but works, one more thing to `TODO` list which will never get a proper fix.